# Regex to grab specific characters from string with spaces

Tags: regex

Here's the string I'm interrogating:

```
[Card-1 Intake : 30 C] [Card-1 Exhaust : 35 C] [Card-1 CPU : 38 C] [Card-1 Switch CPU : 47 C]
```

I am completely lost in how I can use regex (PCRE) to grab the 'Intake' value, i.e. 30.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match just the value, use a look behind:

```
(?<=Intake : )\S+
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/3EIP3ZbWFUwEo1).

---

If look behinds are not supported, use group `1` of:

```
Intake : (\S+)
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/Ue5NC95g7KGxom).

Comment: Thank you this gets me close but Zabbix use of PCRE is returning <empty string> when I test this. Using regexr.com this works nicely though. Perhaps it's the lookbehind that's causing the problem. Is there another way to solve this?

Comment: If look behinds are not supported (they are usualy first tto go), you have to use groups: Try group `1` of `"Intake : (\S+)"`

Comment: Thank you - it was groups I needed. All sorted now!

Answer (score 0):

/Card-1 Intake : (\d+) C/

If you do x = string.match with the regex you can access it with x[1]